# Themself vs. Themselves

Tags: words

The word "themself" seems wrong, and some spell checkers don't like it, e.g Microsoft Word always tries to correct it to "themselves", even in singular. It's in the dictionary though. Is it ok to use, or is "themselves" better, even for singular? E.g.

> If one out walking, and finds **themself** lost...

Which is correct? Why?

---

Note1: I am a fully native Brit, first language English, A in my English Lit and Lang GCSEs, but I just find this word very awkward and don't know why or what to do with it, so I am just here to ask for a full english lesson on the use of this word please.

---

Note2: this question is unrelated to the modern pronoun movement. Any changes that have arisen from it can be mentioned if you feel like it, but that's not what is driving my question.